# Changing color in beamer header (Singapore)

Tags: beamer, color

I am not a TeX-pert and I basically spent half the day trying to figure out the following change to the Singapore theme of beamer.

What I want is to give every sub part (section) a different color in the header. I got so far as to change the color of the shading in the header (see picture).

However, what I additionally want, and don't manage to accomplish, is that the parts "Introduction", "Overview", ... have a different background color (while the color of the shading stays the same). What I have in mind is that the background of the section titles each have a different color and when I am in that section, the shading changes to that particular color.

I don't mind if it is not a fully automated solution, but something handcrafted. Any help is greatly appreciated.

[image: example slide]

**Edit** Upon request, here's the way how I changed the color of the shading. I basically defined a new command which I call after each section command.

```
\newcommand{\changecolor}[1]{
  \setbeamercolor{title}{fg=black}
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {
    color(0cm)=(section in head/foot.bg);%
    color(.95cm)=(#1)
  } 
}
```

**Edit 2** In order to not cause unnecessary effort, here's a very cheap gimp'ed version of my desired result.

[image]

Comment: How did you change the shading? The answer to this question is important because, in the theme, the shading is defined starting from the color given in `section in head/foot`

Comment: I put it in the question.

Comment: @fabee: I've updated my answer, providing a solution.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Now I made a significant simplification to my initial solution. In the code below I used a green-based color scheme, but redefining appropriately `color0`, `color1`,..., `color7`, the colors can be customized. I also added a little (optional) decoration at the bottom right corner of the frames:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{tikz}

\regtotcounter{section}

\definecolor{color0}{HTML}{00675E}

\definecolor{color1}{HTML}{00B366}
\definecolor{color2}{HTML}{34CFCB}
\definecolor{color3}{HTML}{007D48}
\definecolor{color4}{HTML}{80FFC9}
\definecolor{color5}{HTML}{5DCFC3}
\definecolor{color6}{HTML}{BFFFE4}
\definecolor{color7}{HTML}{009E8E}

\makeatletter

\def\sectioncolor{color0}% color to be applied to section headers

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!75!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{use=structure,fg=structure.fg!50!black}
\setbeamercolor{palette quaternary}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{local structure}{fg=color0}
\setbeamercolor{structure}{fg=color0}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=color0}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{block title alerted}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{block title example}{fg=color0}

% Each \section redefines \sectioncolor and applies the shading with this color
% add as many colors as you need
\AtBeginSection{%
  \renewcommand\sectioncolor{%
    \ifcase\value{section} color0\or color1\or color2\or color3\or color4\or color5\else color6\fi}
  \setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=black}%
  \pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
  {%
    color(0.25cm)=(bg);
    color(1.25cm)=(\sectioncolor)%
  }
}

\newlength\sectionboxwd

\AtBeginDocument{%
  \ifnum\totvalue{section}>0 
    \setlength\sectionboxwd{\dimexpr\paperwidth/\totvalue{section}\relax}
  \else
    \setlength\sectionboxwd{\paperwidth}
  \fi
} 

\newcommand\insertcolors{%
  \ifnum\totvalue{section}>0
    \setlength\fboxsep{0pt}%
    \foreach \x in {1,...,\totvalue{section}}
    {\colorbox{color\x}{\phantom{\rule{\dimexpr\the\sectionboxwd\relax}{5ex}}}}%
  \else\fi
}

\setbeamertemplate{section in head/foot}{\setlength\fboxsep{0pt}\hspace{-1.875ex}%
    \parbox[c][4ex][t]{\sectionboxwd}{%
      \hfill\parbox{\dimexpr\sectionboxwd-8pt\relax}{%
      \raggedright\insertsectionhead%
      }\hfill\mbox{}%
    }%
}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{section in head/foot}
    \insertcolors%
    \vskip-4ex%
    \insertsectionnavigationhorizontal{\paperwidth}{\hskip-1.875ex}{\hskip-8pt}\vskip2pt
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
}


\pgfdeclareverticalshading{beamer@headfade}{\paperwidth}
{%
  color(0.25cm)=(bg);
  color(1.25cm)=(color7)%
}

\addtoheadtemplate{}{\pgfuseshading{beamer@headfade}\vskip-1.25cm}

\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\addtobeamertemplate{footline}{}{%
  \hfill\color{\sectioncolor}\rule[0.5cm]{2.5cm}{1pt}\rule[0.5cm]{1pt}{1cm}\hspace*{0.5cm}}

\title{A Beamer Theme}
\subtitle{With colorful headline}
\author{Gonzalo Medina}
\institute{\texttt{tex,stackexchange.com}}
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\end{frame}

\section{Test section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{A test section with a really really long title}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Another test section}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\section{Another test section with a really really long title}

\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Test
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

And some images, showing the titlepage and the first frame of every section in the example; the images illustrate the automatic change of color desired for every section and the colored background in the navigation bar.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

A zoom to one of the frames to show the headline:

[image]

**Remark:**

The code needs two (or three) runs to stabilize.

Comment: I fear that I did explain very well what I actually want. But maybe your answer is already a step in the right direction. I would like to set the background color of the section names in the header. In your example, the background of "test one" would always be blue, the background of "test two" always be green, and so on. Since I don't entirely understand your code, I would still appreciate your help. But thanks so far.

Comment: I added a very cheap gimped version of my desired layout.

Comment: @fabee: I've updated my answer, providing a solution.

Comment: Very nice. A strong candidate to be a part of the actual `beamer` package.

Comment: I think percusse is right. With a little more effort you could turn it into a new beamer theme. It definitely would become my default one.

Comment: I just realized, you could even call it Medina (since it's also a city).

Comment: @fabee: I've updated my answer with the new code.

Comment: @Gonzalo How did you add the decoration at the right bottom corner? I'd like to get a similar effect. I can't spot it on the code.