# Changing color and header of beamer with CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, header-footer, color

How to change the red color for
- the titles
- the topics

How to adjust the position of the header1 and 2?

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


% Set Color ==============================

% Custom colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FDD017}
\definecolor{deep sky blue}{HTML}{3BB9FF}
\definecolor{light sky blue}{HTML}{82CAFA}

\makeatletter
\definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
\definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=myforeground, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background}{fg=myforeground, bg=mybackground}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black, bg=gray!30!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=black, bg=gray!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=gold}
\makeatother
% Set Color ==============================



\title{Title1}
\subtitle{Title2}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}


\begin{document}

\frame{

}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Header1}
\subsection{Header2}
\frame{\frametitle{Topic1}
%
HTML color codes are the \textbf{hexadecimal triplets} representing the colors red, green, and blue.
\vspace{0.25cm}
%
These color codes can be used to change the color of the background, text, and tables on a web page.
}
%
%
\end{document}
```

Title1 and 2
[image: Title]

Topic1 and Header1 & 2
[image: Topic]

Align text left or right, center
[image: Align text left or right, center]

Comment: possible duplicate? http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53288/changing-color-in-beamer-header-singapore

Comment: What do you mean by "adjusting the position"? Do you want to chenge which parameter(s) exactly?

Comment: I mean the horizontal alignment of text. Align the text to the left, right or center

Comment: @Langevin I think I still don't understand. Do you want the entries in the table of contents to be, for example, centered?

Comment: @Langevin A now I see what you mean. In some minutes I'll give an answer.

Comment: I am sorry to bother you, but may I ask if there's any problem with the answer below? I ask because I noticed that you have asked several follow-up questions (which you have accepted), but since you haven't accepted the answer to this one I wonder if there's something wrong with it.

Comment: @Gonzalo Medina Your answer is so useful. I am a newcomer for this website. This website has a lot of features. I am learning to use them. Anyway, you are so cool.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To change the color for the frame title and for the title and subtitle, you need to redefine the `beamer` colors `frametitle` and `title`:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{<color>}
\setbeamercolor{title}{<color>}
```

to change the position of the headers, you need to redefine the `headline` template as defined in the outer theme `infolines` (internally used by `CambridgeUS`). Here's the original definition:

```
\defbeamertemplate*{headline}{infolines theme}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,left]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}
```

As you can see, the alignment for the first `beamercolorbox` is `right`, and the one for the second box is `left`: you can change these as you wish.

In the following example I used a shade of cyan for the titles (not the best choice) and I used `center` for both boxes in the `headline`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


% Set Color ==============================

% Custom colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FDD017}
\definecolor{deep sky blue}{HTML}{3BB9FF}
\definecolor{light sky blue}{HTML}{82CAFA}

\definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
\definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=myforeground, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background}{fg=myforeground, bg=mybackground}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black, bg=gray!30!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=black, bg=gray!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=gold}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=cyan!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=cyan!80!black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

% Set Color ==============================

\title{Title1}
\subtitle{Title2}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}


\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Header1}
\subsection{Header2}
\frame{\frametitle{Topic1}
%
HTML color codes are the \textbf{hexadecimal triplets} representing the colors red, green, and blue.
%
These color codes can be used to change the color of the background, text, and tables on a web page.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Gonzalo Medina for your very useful input. How do you change the color of the bands of the frame titles?
For example, in the last slide, "Topic1" is colored in cyan!80!black. But how do I change the pale grey color of the band that contains the title?

Comment: @user32950 use `bg=<color>` in the `frametitle` color specification, as in `\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=cyan!80!black,bg=red}`.