# Question about beamer - Head shaded with CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, color

Related to my [previous question about beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113814/changing-color-and-header-of-beamer-with-cambridgeus/113817?noredirect=1#113817), now I have another one:

- How to change the color on the head shaded from the light gray to the light green.

[image: Head shaded]

Comment: This colour, and the hader/footer colours (both foreground and background) aswell are driven by `pallete primary`, `pallete secondary` and `pallete tertiary` and can be (re)defined. by `\setbeamercolor` command.

Comment: It's a good practise to ask only one question per query. [TeX.SX starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436). So please remove one.

Comment: I found this link http://www.cpt.univ-mrs.fr/~masson/latex/Beamer-appearance-cheat-sheet.pdf
It shows color palettes commands, but there is not presented about head shaded.
palette primary
palette secondary
palette tertiary
palette quaternary
palette sidebar primary
palette sidebar secondary
palette sidebar tertiary

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be derived from your previous question.

The frame title is defined by:

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=cyan!80!black}
```

So the specification sets the foreground (fg). To specify the background (bg) add

```
\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=cyan!80!black,bg=green!60!white}
```

[image]