# Question about beamer - Cambria font with CambridgeUS

Tags: beamer, fonts

Related to my [previous question about beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113814/changing-color-and-header-of-beamer-with-cambridgeus/113817?noredirect=1#113817), now I have another one:

- How to set Cambria font for mathematical equations and Times New Roman or Arial font for regular text

Comment: Do you use `xelatex` or `lualatex`?

Comment: @Marco Daniel, I use xelatex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include this in the preamble:

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{Cambria Math}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}
```

Then compile your document with `xelatex` instead of `pdflatex`, otherwise it won't work. AFAIK you can't use Cambria Math unless you switch to `xelatex`.

<sub>On a personal note, I strongly recommend against using Times New Roman or Arial in a presentation :)</sub>

Comment: Your personal note should be bold :-)