# Beamer CambridgeUS - How to add logo above the title

Tags: beamer, logos

Related to my [previous question about beamer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/113814/changing-color-and-header-of-beamer-with-cambridgeus/113817?noredirect=1#113817), now I have another one:

- How to add logo above the title.

[image: LOGO]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`CambridgeUS` uses the `default` `title page` template which inserts the title graphic at the end; you can redefine the template to include it before the title, and then use

```
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[<options>]{image}}
```

A complete example, including your settings from the linked question:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{CambridgeUS}


% Set Color ==============================

% Custom colors
\usepackage{xcolor}

% http://www.computerhope.com/htmcolor.htm
\definecolor{gold}{HTML}{FDD017}
\definecolor{deep sky blue}{HTML}{3BB9FF}
\definecolor{light sky blue}{HTML}{82CAFA}

\definecolor{mybackground}{HTML}{82CAFA}
\definecolor{myforeground}{HTML}{0000A0}

\setbeamercolor{normal text}{fg=black,bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{alerted text}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{example text}{fg=black}

\setbeamercolor{background canvas}{fg=myforeground, bg=white}
\setbeamercolor{background}{fg=myforeground, bg=mybackground}

\setbeamercolor{palette primary}{fg=black, bg=gray!30!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette secondary}{fg=black, bg=gray!20!white}
\setbeamercolor{palette tertiary}{fg=black, bg=gold}

\setbeamercolor{frametitle}{fg=cyan!80!black}
\setbeamercolor{title}{fg=cyan!80!black}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}
{
  \leavevmode%
  \hbox{%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{section in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{section in head/foot}\insertsectionhead\hspace*{2ex}
  \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.5\paperwidth,ht=2.65ex,dp=1.5ex,center]{subsection in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{subsection in head/foot}\hspace*{2ex}\insertsubsectionhead
  \end{beamercolorbox}}%
  \vskip0pt%
}

\makeatletter
\defbeamertemplate*{title page}{mydefault}[1][]
{
  \vbox{}
  \vfill
  \begin{centering}
    {\usebeamercolor[fg]{titlegraphic}\inserttitlegraphic\par}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{title}
      \usebeamerfont{title}\inserttitle\par%
      \ifx\insertsubtitle\@empty%
      \else%
        \vskip0.25em%
        {\usebeamerfont{subtitle}\usebeamercolor[fg]{subtitle}\insertsubtitle\par}%
      \fi%     
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \vskip1em\par
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{author}
      \usebeamerfont{author}\insertauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{institute}
      \usebeamerfont{institute}\insertinstitute
    \end{beamercolorbox}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[sep=8pt,center,#1]{date}
      \usebeamerfont{date}\insertdate
    \end{beamercolorbox}\vskip0.5em
  \end{centering}
  \vfill
}
\setbeamertemplate{title page}[mydefault][colsep=-4bp,rounded=true,shadow=\beamer@themerounded@shadow]
\makeatother

% Set Color ==============================

\title{Title1}
\subtitle{Title2}
\author{Author}
\institute{Institute}
\date{Date}
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[height=2cm]{ctanlion}}


\begin{document}

\frame{\maketitle}

\section[Outline]{}
\frame{\tableofcontents}

\section{Header1}
\subsection{Header2}
\frame{\frametitle{Topic1}
%
HTML color codes are the \textbf{hexadecimal triplets} representing the colors red, green, and blue.
%
These color codes can be used to change the color of the background, text, and tables on a web page.
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can add a figure to the title frame by using the command `\titlegraphic{}`. The standard behaviour puts the graphic at the bottom. However instead of redefining the default behaviour you can work with `\raisebox` whereby a `\smash` is needed:

```
\titlegraphic{\leavevmode\smash{\raisebox{6cm}{foo}}}
```

For "foo" you can use `\includegraphics` or whatever you want.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I didn't thought that. My answer is only a dirty hack ;-)